Firebase hosting rewrites to cloud run in config but redirects in preview or deploy
I have a flask app running on a cloud run service and want to use firebase hosting for static files, CDN caching, etc.
When I test locally with the emulator, everything works perfectly and I get my site served through a local host port with correct cache headers.
When I deploy to a preview or live channel, and visit the link I get fully redirected to the cloud run service url. I have NOT got any domain mapping set in cloud run, although I accidentally did at the start.
The following is my firebase.json
{
  "hosting": {
    "site": "my-app-demo",
    "public": "src/app/static",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "private, max-age=3600"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "/static/**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "public, max-age=86400"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,svg,css,js}",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "public, max-age=86400"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "run": {
          "serviceId": "my-app-demo",
          "region": "my-region"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


I've tried creating new sites on firebase hosting and deploying to those but no change.
